# R: Makes rows column in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have an unusual dataset which I'd like to alter to use in some analysis. The dataset currently looks like

```
Country | Predictor | Value
  VN          P1        NA 
  VN          P2       .05
  RS          P1       .12
  RS          P2       .23
  SA          P1       .88
  SA          P2       .01
```

I would like to change the dataset so each `Predictor` is it's own column. So,

```
Country | P1 | P2 
  VN      NA  .05
  RS     .12  .23
  SA     .88  .01
```

I've never come across this problem so I'm stumped. How should I go about rearranging my dataset? Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the cases where `reshape`ing is useful.  We convert the 'long' format to 'wide' using `dcast` from `reshape2`.  We specify the 'Value' column as the `value.var` and use the formula `Country~Predictor` so that the unique elements of 'Predictor' forms the column names.

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df1, Country~Predictor, value.var='Value')
#  Country   P1   P2
#1      VN   NA 0.05
#2      RS 0.12 0.23
#3      SA 0.88 0.01
```

---

Or another option is `spread` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
spread(df1, Predictor, Value)
#  Country   P1   P2
#1      VN   NA 0.05
#2      RS 0.12 0.23
#3      SA 0.88 0.01
```

---

Or a `base R` with `reshape`

```
reshape(df1, idvar='Country', timevar='Predictor', direction='wide')
#  Country Value.P1 Value.P2
#1      VN       NA     0.05
#3      RS     0.12     0.23
#5      SA     0.88     0.01
```

or`xtabs`

```
xtabs(Value~Country+Predictor, df1)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Country = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), 
.Label = c("VN", 
"RS", "SA"), class = "factor"), Predictor = c("P1", "P2", "P1", 
"P2", "P1", "P2"), Value = c(NA, 0.05, 0.12, 0.23, 0.88, 0.01
)), .Names = c("Country", "Predictor", "Value"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: The `reshape` method works well. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Black No problem.  Glad to help you.